# Simple Servlet deploy on Tomcat eclipse

Tags: java, servlets

I'm following Head First Java.

I created a simple servlet as they instructed but they did not write how to deploy it.

I'm trying to deploy it on Tomcat 7 and i have set it up via eclipse.

However im getting a 404 page error.

i created a web.xml i also placed the class files in WEB-INF/classes.

Here is the code.

```
package org.code;

import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class KathyServlet extends HttpServlet { 

public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws  ServletException, IOException  {
 PrintWriter out;
 String title = "PhraseOMatic has generated the following phrase.";
     response.setContentType("text/html");
 out = response.getWriter();

    out.println("<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>");
out.println("PhraseOmatic");
out.println("</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>");
out.println("<H1>" + title + "</H1>");
out.println("<P>" + PhraseOMatic2.makePhrase());
    out.println("<P><a href=\"KathyServlet\">make another phrase</a></p>");
out.println("</BODY></HTML>");

out.close();
}
}
```

---

other java code file:

```
package org.code;

public class PhraseOMatic2 {
public static String makePhrase() {

 // make three sets of words to choose from
String[] wordListOne = {"24/7","multi-Tier","30,000 foot","B-to-B","win-win","front-     end", "web-based","pervasive", "smart", "six-sigma","critical-path", "dynamic"};

String[] wordListTwo = {"empowered", "sticky", "valued-added", "oriented", "centric", "distributed", "clustered", "branded","outside-the-box", "positioned", "networked", "focused", "leveraged", "aligned", "targeted", "shared", "cooperative", "accelerated"};

String[] wordListThree = {"process", "tipping point", "solution", "architecture", "core competency", "strategy", "mindshare", "portal", "space", "vision", "paradigm", "mission"};

// find out how many words are in each list
int oneLength = wordListOne.length;
int twoLength = wordListTwo.length;
int threeLength = wordListThree.length;

// generate three random numbers, to pull random words from each list
int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * twoLength);
int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * threeLength);

// now build a phrase
String phrase = wordListOne[rand1] + " " + wordListTwo[rand2] + " " +    wordListThree[rand3];

// now return it
return ("What we need is a " + phrase);
} 
}
```

---

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>HFJse</display-name>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>kathyServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.yasin.KathyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>KathyServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/snoop/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

our servlet calss is in the package `org.code`, but the class name you set in the web.xml is `org.yasin.KathyServlet`.

Moreover, you gave the name `kathyServlet` to your servlet in the web.xml, but your mapping uses the name `KathyServlet`. Servlet names are case-sensitive.

Comment: sorry i had pasted the wrong xml, i changed the xml to the correct package name but it still gave the same error, but i did not notice the lower case kathy and once i changed that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

If that code is right you web.xml is bad. Your are defining a servlet-class using:

**org.yasin.KathyServlet**

and your Servlet is:

**org.code.KathyServlet**

The Servlet that you are using in your web.xml need to point to the correct package and Sevlet name.

You should see a ClassNotFound in your tomcat log associated with you 404 error.